# Beginning a repeat with a tied note in guitar pro 6

Tags: guitar, tablature, guitar-pro, repeats, ties

I'm trying to tab out a song in guitar pro 6 and I have a section that repeats.  The section begins with a tied note from the previous measure, then when it repeats I want the last note of the last measure to be tied to the first note of the repeat.

The problem is when I tried this, the last chord does not get tied to the start of the repeat, it just plays it like an eighth note and then mutes the tied half after the repeat.  An image is shown below.

[image: example of score with ties across a repeat barline]

The note I am talking about is the last chord on the 7th fret.  When the repeat goes through, it is not cleanly tied to the first chord the second time around.  It just cuts out the (7) chord at the start and continues.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible.
It is a problem that I reported years ago and they should fix it in the next version. In the meantime, I don't see any workaround except adding a text note to inform the reader that it's tied, but GP won't play it tied...

Comment: I have to try it when I get home to double check, but I think I tried this in the new version (Guitar Pro 7) and the issue is still there...

Comment: yes, still there :(

Comment: Yes. Still there. 24 Oct 2021. V7.5

Comment: Still a bug/issue as of 5/2023. They should really fix this.

Comment: Years later in GP8 this is STILL an issue UGHHH